# Flow error when using react-apollo Query component render prop

Tags: flowtype, react-apollo, apollo-client, flow-typed

I have the following code:

```js
import { Query } from 'react-apollo';

type Post = {
  id: string
};

interface Data {
  posts: Array<Post>;
}

class PostsQuery extends Query<Data> {}
```

When using the above as follows:

```js
<PostsQuery query={POSTS_QUERY}>
  {({ loading, data }) => {
    ...
    {data.posts.map(...)}
    ...
  }
</PostsQuery>
```

I get the following error from flow:

`Error:(151, 27) Cannot get 'data.posts' because property 'posts' is missing in object type [1].`

Any idea why?

I did use `flow-typed` to add `apollo-client_v2.x.x.js` to my project by the way

Comment: I know this sounds like a lot of work, but if you can isolate the required typedefs from apollo-client and make a http://flow.org/try example, you're more likely to get an answer.

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: You can't use `import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import { Query } from 'react-apollo';` on flow.org/try. You would need to manually copy typedefs for those parts into the flow.org/try session. As you can see, the error on Flow.org/try doesn't match your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### How to make a reproducible example and research the problem

So the first thing we need to do while analyzing these types is to go lookup the typedefs in the [flow-typed repo](https://github.com/flow-typed/flow-typed). I went ahead a copy-pasted the [react-apollo typedefs](https://github.com/flow-typed/flow-typed/blob/master/definitions/npm/react-apollo_v2.x.x/flow_v0.58.x-/react-apollo_v2.x.x.js) into flow.org/try, modified them slightly (added an `any` somewhere, set `gql` to `any`), and was able to replicate your errors:

([Try](https://flow.org/try/#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) - Scroll to the bottom for your code)

Referencing the [relevant lines of the `QueryRenderProps` type](https://github.com/flow-typed/flow-typed/blob/c82b76264935e6f69001636fa825474194c320da/definitions/npm/react-apollo_v2.x.x/flow_v0.58.x-/react-apollo_v2.x.x.js#L905), we can see why flow is throwing the error:

```
{
     data: TData | {||} | void,
     ...
}
```

It looks like data can either be `TData` (probably what you want), an empty object, or undefined. Cross checking this with the [typescript typings for react-apollo](https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/blob/3c231f3ceff7aeccb3da1eecb6ccabfc4c7d7434/src/Query.tsx#L89), we can see why the type is the way it is:

```
{
    ...
    // we create an empty object to make checking for data
    // easier for consumers (i.e. instead of data && data.user
    // you can just check data.user) this also makes destructring
    // easier (i.e. { data: { user } })
    // however, this isn't realy possible with TypeScript that
    // I'm aware of. So intead we enforce checking for data
    // like so result.data!.user. This tells TS to use TData
    // XXX is there a better way to do this?
    data: TData | undefined;
    ...
}
```

Unfortunately, due to the extreme length of these links and stackoverflow's limit on answer lengths, I have to continue my answer in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51215833/flow-error-when-using-react-apollo-query-component-render-prop/51309685#51309685). I guess this answer can serve as an explanation of how to start debugging the problem.

Comment: If I may bring your attention to this, I would be thankful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51231324/flow-property-missing-in-object-type?noredirect=1#comment89555049_51231324

Answer (score 3):

### Solution to the problem

Continued from the answer explaining how to make a [verifiable example and research the problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51215833/flow-error-when-using-react-apollo-query-component-render-prop/51309648#51309648)

So it looks like this part of react-apollo isn't typed in such a way to make accessing the `data` contents straightforward. Okay, that's fine, we can take their recommendation on destructuring and check for empty data. At the same time, we can also add an `id` property to the `Post` type so flow stops complaining about that:

([Try](https://flow.org/try/#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) - Scroll to bottom for relevant code)

```
type Post = {
  id: string,
  title: string;
};

...snip...

// Look ma, no errors
class Search extends React.Component<{}> {
  render = () => (
    <PostsQuery query={QUERY}>
    {({ loading, error, data }) => {
      if (error) {
        return <p>Error</p>
      }
      if (loading) return <p>Loading</p>
      const nonNullData = (data || {})
      const dataWithAllPosts = {allPosts: [], ...nonNullData}
      const {allPosts} = dataWithAllPosts
      if (allPosts.length == 0) {
        return <p>Empty response or something</p>
      }
      return (
          <div>
            {allPosts.map(post => {
              return <div key={post.id}>{post.title}</div>;
            })}
          </div>
      );
    }}
    </PostsQuery>
  );
}
```

I'm not familiar with the react-apollo library, so I'm not sure how you want to handle that case where there are no posts. I just added a message as seen above. It's entirely possible that the case never occurs (again, you would know better than I do). If that's the case, you might want to skip some of the above steps and just assert the desired type with a [cast through any](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/casting/#toc-type-casting-through-any).

Comment: Thank you very much for such an effort :)