# Flow property missing in object type

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

I have the following Flow `Props` type for a component:

```
type Props = {
  // <...>
  update: ({ dates?: DateRange }) => void
};
```

I also have the following exported type:

```
export type SearchContextType = {
  // <...>
  update: ({ dates?: DateRange, location?: Location }) => void
};
```

When I try to pass props to the first component using the second type I get the following error:

> Error:(99, 23) Cannot create `MyComponent` element because property `location` is missing in object type [1](https://flow.org/try/#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-hmO0Ox02VxBz1kb2+sDyxmKzHKs2zEwMc38K26M9Xsj8YClyy8ENAA) but exists in object type [2] in the first argument of property `update`.

I understand the error, but my question is: how can I get around it properly?

[Example](https://flow.org/try/#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-hmO0Ox02VxBz1kb2+sDyxmKzHKs2zEwMc38K26M9Xsj8YClyy8ENAA)

Comment: Maybe you should share the actual code where you are using the types?

Comment: I've setup a Flow try repo and i'm not able to reproduce your issue, feel free to edit, don't forget to select your Flow version:

https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBLAtgBzgJwBcwAlAUwEMBjQgGjAG8wBhOXOAOzI+IF8wo+NmADk+SjREBudIQCeOMizY4ACkJwBnMAF5GqMGAAmFQmU0AuMJsL4MHAOa0DYAK44TZqwAomn8wD8VjZ2jmC8AJS6AHxgAG5wGEaovDKoZAAeeERg8opgAMqU+FQAFqw8mYTqcFq6+ob+lta29k4u8FSmGJzBrY7Ohu7+Pn6mgX2hTmCd3ZxBLVPhUTqxCUkpaVQwFJraRRQl5ZxmGcRV3EbarOxcPAA8B0cVp9UamrEMvOjbu9cqYAuHCuylu3EI9xuanenxc4mBZHwYG8UQYLkMVE4NkYxnGmnow3G4XqhFKGE0ADocO8ZIZDOJCK58BwwI9imUXlVcWZNDoGE1+ISzHyhWR+LNCD0ODoRDzCCIwMBorTwilUEA

Answer (score 0):

First - we will simplify the example:

```
type SubType = { dates?: string, location?: string };
type Foo = (arg: SubType) => void;

type SuperType = { dates?: string };
type Bar = (arg: SuperType) => void;

function convert (arg: Foo): Bar {
  return arg;
  //     ^ Cannot return `arg` because property `location` is missing in `SuperType` [1] but exists in `SubType` [2] in the first argument.
}
```

In other word we just use typecasting to convert `Foo` into `Bar`:

```
const anyObj = ({}: any);

((anyObj: Foo): Bar);
//        ^ Cannot cast object literal to `Bar` because property `location` is missing in `SuperType` [1] but exists in `SubType` [2] in the first argument.
```

Or we can say that we convert `SuperType` into `SubType`

```
((anyObj: SuperType): SubType);
//        ^ Cannot cast `anyObj` to `SubType` because property `location` is missing in `SuperType` [1] but exists in `SubType` [2].
```

To convert `SuperType` into `SubType` we can use `$Shape`:

> Copies the shape of the type supplied, but marks every field optional.

```
// Correct
((anyObj: SuperType): $Shape<SubType>);
```

**TLDR:**

```
export type SearchContextType = {
  dates: DateRange,
  location: GoogleMapPosition,
  update: ($Shape<{ dates?: DateRange, location?: GoogleMapPosition }>) => void
  //       ^ add `$Shape`
};
```

[Corrected Example](https://flow.org/try/#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-DM7s9XpsrmjQbIIbDYA1XK1RJ19tmJgYDv4zt01-vZH4wFrll4saAA)